# Aumentar Performance Bat

Tags: batch, prompt, ms-dos

Atualmente tenho um .bat que roda copiando arquivos da rede de um servidor para outro. Esta me facilitou muito um trabalho que era feito manualmente, porém, notei que ao remover alguns incrementos (floreios) do .bat, ele melhorou sua performance de execução nas cópias dos arquivos.

Estarei postando o código do .bat e se possível, poderiam me ajudar a performá-la, tornando-a mais curta, performática, mas mantendo seu principal objetivo.

O objetivo dela é pegar ids em uma lista.txt e copiar os arquivos com os respectivos IDs para outra pasta da rede. OBS: eu estava despejando em um log caso não encontrasse o arquivo, mas não me é necessário por isso removi.

```
@echo off

rem Pasta para colar os arquivos copiados.  
set minhaPasta=I:\ARQUIVOS_ENCONTRADOS

rem Arquivo txt que o processo vai ler com o nome dos arquivos "LISTA DOS IDs".  
set meuArquivo=I:PASTA\lista.txt  

rem Pasta onde estão os arquivos que devem ser copiados, tem que ter a barra no final "\".  
set pastaArquivos=J:\  

rem Extensão dos arquivos a serem copiados.  
set tipo=.xml  

rem Comando para criar as pastas caso elas não existam no meu computador  
rem if not exist %minhaPasta% md %minhaPasta%  

rem Caso o arquivo que tem os nomes dos arquivos não exista vai gravar o log informando.  

rem Inicio da verificação  
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%meuArquivo%) do (      
        copy %pastaArquivos%*%%A*%tipo% %minhaPasta%   
    )
pause
```

Por acaso é possível melhorar a performance deste .bat? Teriam alguma dica?
 Nem que seja incluir ou diminuir variáveis, remover comentários, executar local e nem utilizar variaveis, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Não acho que vai melhorar a performance no BATCH em si, ele parece simples o suficiente, mas evite usar caracteres especiais mesmo nos comentários, como letras com acentos e cedilha, também evite deixar muitos espaços antes das quebras de linha, pode não ser nada, mas também é algo a ser escrito na tela do prompt de comando.

No **FOR** tem duas vezes o "*", a não ser que seja necessário para o padrão do nome usados nos arquivos.

Eu fiz o teste simulando o código, mas ao invés de copiar pra outra máquina, fiz copiar para um PEN-DRIVE.

Pra ver o script rodar com mais clareza eu coloquei esses comandos no início:

```
@echo off
cls
```

Você pode fazer uma verificação ou parar o Script caso algum arquivo não seja encontrado com `errorlevel` dentro do `FOR`:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo ERRO AO TRANSFERIR ARQUIVO DE ID %%A
```

O que você pode melhorar é a comunicação entre as máquinas, colocando cabo de rede evitando o uso de conexão *wireless*, também fixando os IP's com a mesma classe pra evitar queda da rede.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use os caminhos qualificados invés de variáveis

2) Direto crie a pasta ocultando o erro em caso de já existir **`2>nul mkdir "I:\ARQUIVOS_ENCONTRADOS"`**

3) Agrupando **`()`** e redirecionado **`>>`** para o arquivo de saída **`>>"%temp%\Log_Rotina_.log" (..)`**

4) Use caminhos ao invés de variáveis no comando **`copy`** e também redirecionando **`>nul`**

- **`copy "J:\%%~A*.xml" "I:\ARQUIVOS_ENCONTRADOS\" >nul`**

  ---

```bat
@echo off & 2>nul mkdir "J:\SUA_PASTA_DESTINO\"
>> "%temp%\Log_Rotina_MeuArquivo_MinhaPasta_.log" (
for /F tokens^=* %%A in ("I:\PASTA\lista.txt"
)do copy "J:\%%~A*.xml" "I:\ARQUIVOS_ENCONTRADOS\" >nul )
```

---

- **ou...**

  ---

```bat
@echo off &(2>nul mkdir "J:\SUA_PASTA_DESTINO\")& >> "%temp%\Log_Rotina_MeuArquivo_MinhaPasta_.log" (for /F tokens^=* %%A in "I:\PASTA\lista.txt")do copy "J:\%%~A*.xml" "I:\ARQUIVOS_ENCONTRADOS\" >nul )`
```

---